# Where can I find my Rhythmbox playlist file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhythmbox

I'm trying to locate my Rhythmbox playlist file.  I've moved all my music files off of a hard drive from my old computer that no longer works.  Does anyone know where to find the file containing the playlist info?

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, it appears that they are located in a hidden file called playlists.xml. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (which has Rhythmbox 0.12.8).

```
/home/username/.local/share/rhythmbox/playlists.xml
```